# Dart Class starting with uppercase (p.e. int, bool, num, ... should be Int, Bool, Num, ... !?)

Tags: dart

I believe that a language becomes widely accepted and popular as follows foundations of computing, definitions and conventions well standardized.

Everything in Dart is object, in theory, all objects are created from a class. As a convention (and standardization), a class definition should start with a capital letter (like String , List , etc.)

So why the basic types int, bool, num, etc., in Dart do not start with a capital letter, like Int (Integer), Bool (Boolean), Num (Number), ...?

I just would like to understand!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's for convenience for developers coming from other languages like Java, C#, C, C++, JavaScript, ... where they are used to lowercase type names for primitive types.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the "primitives" in Dart act a little different than the other classes. For example, you can't extend int, while you can extend a non-primitive like HttpServer. Unfortunately, capitalization isn't 100% on telling you if something has this behaviour, as String can't be extended either even though it's capitalized.

Comment: It was 100% for familiarity and convenience. The names are the same as the commonly used names in Java, because that allows you to copy code almost verbatim from Java to Dart, and allows Java programmers to write like they are used to. Likewise, you can use `var` to declare a variable like in JavaScript, so JavaScript programmers can also write like they are used to. Personally, I'd have preferred "string" to be lower-case too, like in C#, but a choice had to be made.

Comment: Okay, I understand that there is an alignment concern about the legacy, though as new language, could review "strange" question of the oldest languages, facilitating the understanding of new developers as well as increasing acceptance in universities who like to standardized naming conventions.

Comment: That's a ridiculous design choice. Grrr OCD kicking in !

Comment: @Ced yup :D . . . .